# En que caso se usa req.params, req.query y req.body?

Tags: json, api, mongodb

me gustaria saber en que caso usaria cada una para la creacion de una API, me gustaria saber porque tengo una API y quiero paginas con ella y de esos elementos solo uso el req.body, pero los otros no se como funcionarían, me gustaria paginar y hacer dos otres cosas mas con la API para un proyecto de la escuela.

ejemplo: sacar por usuario o por estudiantes imaginando que cada estudiante tiene mas de un proyecto

```
https:api.com/?user=juan
```

y en caso de que Juan tenga mas de 10 yo solo saque 5 y queden 5 para cuando vuelva y haga la peticion salgan los otros 5 y los primeros hagan un findAndUpdate a otra condicion, ejemplo revisados,

```
 https:api.com/?user=juan&proj=5
```

me pueden explicar el uso y como hacerlo  ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`req.params` sería para obtener información de un elemento de un catálogo de colecciones, por ejemplo si tuvieras una `API` donde `/collections` te da el listado de colecciones. Pero queremos ver mas información a detalle un elemento la url sería `/collections/5` donde internamente nuestro path es `/collections/:id`, entonces a través de `req.params` podemos obtener el valor de id => `req.params.id`.

Mientras que `req.body` nos sirve para obtener los valores que un formulario envía a nuestra API. Asi `req.query` hace referencia a la `querystring` o parámetros que pasemos en la `url` de la `API`, estos son los que usarías para hacer la paginación.

Tomando como ejemplo `/collections` , implementando la paginación veríamos algo así: `/collections?page=1` o `/collections?page=1&limit=20` , ya desde el `backend` con `req.query` podemos obtener los valores como `req.query.page` (para la página que queremos ver) , `req.query.limit` (por si deseamos ver mas elementos que los que mostramos por defecto)

Tomando el ejemplo de juan y reacomodándolo:

`/users/:id/projects` [aqui aplicamos el paginado]

`/users/:id/projects/:id_proyecto` [para ver el detalle de un proyecto en particular]

Comment: gracias, es lo que deseaba entender